# jquery scroll from top to bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to scroll a page with content from top to bottom 
and a navigation have 'show top' anchor. when i clicked on 'show top' anchor then a page(which is not showing before) will scroll from top to main screen area with content.

```
.topPage{
    width:1280px; 
    color:#000; 
    float:left; 
    position:relative;
    background:#E6E6E8;
}


$('a.scrollToBottom').click(function(){
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
scrollTop: $("#topPage").offset().top
  }, 2000);
// event.preventDefault();
});
```

But the page (topPage) scrolling from bottom to top..
I need to scroll from top to bottom to show in main screen area.

Comment: Its difficult to understand what u want from the question. Tell us clearly, what u want, possibly a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `div` is placed at a negative `top` offset. You can't scroll past 0 vertically, so the scroll stops once you hit the top and you won't be able to see all of your `div`.

If you want the *`div`* to animate, consider using

```
$('.topcontent').stop().animate({
    top: 0
}, 2000);
```

instead.

Comment: but i neeed to scroll it from top to bottom

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "scroll from top to bottom". Do you want the div to move? the page to scroll? Do you want the div to look like it's sliding out?

Comment: Then, as I said, you will have to scroll the `div` to animate in, because right now you have placed it above the page boundaries (and thus you cannot scroll to it).

Answer (score 0):

To automatically scroll animated to the bottom of the page (or, enough that the whole page is inside the viewport), I use this:

```
  $(window.opera ? 'html' : 'body,html,document').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $('body').height() - $(window).height()) 
  }, 1000);
```